# Ransack Sorting, scope and ransacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Let say I am willing to do the search for my listing site with two fields one for city and other for listing name.

But in my search page. I also want to add some filters to this search. My model also contains tags using `acts_as_taggable_on`.

Basically a search similar to yelp.com

1. How to update the params when clicking the checkbox of tags.
2. Also need to add the sorting with `Best Match, Highest Rated and Most Reviewed`.
3. For Highly Rated. I am having a `average_rating` method which will output the integer value. Need to take that value with the `ransacker`. The method i am using in shown below.

   ```
   def average_rating
     total = self.comments.map do |c|
       c.rating
     end.reduce(0, :+)
     total == 0 ? 0.0 : average = total/self.comments_count.to_f
   end

   ransacker :average_rating do
     "what need to be mentioned here."
   end
   ```

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/36

Comment: Ransack searches ActiveRecord objects. Trying to filter based on model methods is going to make you sad (not to mention be insanely slow). Use a counter-cache field in the table to store the average rating, and query on that.

Comment: Or... You need to turn that method into some SQL that you can include in a scope or view.

Comment: I just tried by Pavling way to create a table. It worked perfectly.